# Injecting queries into DAOs via a spring config file

Tags: java, spring

I'm looking at my project's DAO class which has native sql query in java class. there are different queries based on different condition. I'm planning to take out these query from java class. It can be something like this -

```
<bean name="hibernateRuleDao" class="com.xyz.dao.RuleDao">
  <property name="ruleForSystemQuery">
    <value>
      select distinct rule from NormalRule as rule 
      inner join fetch rule.dimensions dimensions
      where rule.system = :system and rule.status = :status
    </value>
  </property>
  <property name="ruleAuditQuery">
    <value>
       select ra from RuleAudit ra where ra.rule.name =
       :ruleName
    </value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Is this the right approach ? Any other better approach to do this ?

Note: Using hibernate/jpa named query is not feasible in my use case.

Comment: I would not bother with this approach, it just seems like extra complexity for no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to facilitate SQL modification without code recompilation, then yes this will do. You just need to inject RuleDao into your DAO classes.

However in my opinion SQL query modification should go through standard software lifecycle (design, implement, test, operate). So I'm happy with my SQL queries being hardcoded into DAO classes.

Comment: IMO, this helps to keep all query at one place (i.e spring configuration file) and DAO looks cleaner and avoids spring manipulation etc. One can argue about messing around with spring config file. Other approach could have been to maintain in  properties file and inject it using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Just trying to find best approach to handle such cases.